# Strange, float type parameter passing in function in windows

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, floating-point, function-call

There is a piece of code confuse me, which runs in windows!
Here is the code:

```
#define point_float2uint(x) *((unsigned int *)&x)


float divide_1000(float y)
{
    float v = y / 1000.0f;
    return v;
}

float divide_1000(int y)
{
    float v = float(y) / 1000.0f;
    return v;
}


void float_test(void)
{
    int num[5] = {67975500, 67251500, 67540620, 69435500, 70171500};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        int a = num[i];
        float af_f = divide_1000(float(a));
        float af_i = divide_1000((a));
        printf("src num:%d,  af_f:%f, %x, af_i:%f, %x\n", num[i], af_f, point_float2uint(af_f), af_i, point_float2uint(af_i));
    }
}
```

Here is the output, compiled by vs2005:

```
src num:67975500,  af_f:67975.507813, 4784c3c1, af_i:67975.500000, 4784c3c0
src num:67251500,  af_f:67251.507813, 478359c1, af_i:67251.500000, 478359c0
src num:67540620,  af_f:67540.625000, 4783ea50, af_i:67540.617188, 4783ea4f
src num:69435500,  af_f:69435.507813, 47879dc1, af_i:69435.500000, 47879dc0
src num:70171500,  af_f:70171.507813, 47890dc1, af_i:70171.500000, 47890dc0
```

The question is: why I use the "**divide_1000**", get the different result in windows? This is not what I want!
And I find that not all the integer result in different, but some just like the code above.

Here is the the output, comipled by gcc4.4.5 in debian:

```
src num:67975500,  af_f:67975.507812, 4784c3c1, af_i:67975.507812, 4784c3c1
src num:67251500,  af_f:67251.507812, 478359c1, af_i:67251.507812, 478359c1
src num:67540620,  af_f:67540.625000, 4783ea50, af_i:67540.625000, 4783ea50
src num:69435500,  af_f:69435.507812, 47879dc1, af_i:69435.507812, 47879dc1
src num:70171500,  af_f:70171.507812, 47890dc1, af_i:70171.507812, 47890dc1
```

I get the same result in useing different function "**divide_1000**". That's what I want.

Comment: Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the question here maybe is for example why in other compilers the result is different, what kind of optimizations they are addressing differently from one another?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg  Thank you for your help. But I think I know what's wrong with Floating-Point. Which confuse me is, why there are different results between first way and second way? Is there is an answer in "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"?

Comment: @DRC I use vs2005 to compile the code~

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I think the problem is more subtle here. In both cases the integer is cast to float before the division. This is rather related to the optimizer doing the whole computation in doubles (or even higher precision) for `af_i` and then converts the result to float. In the other case, the parameter is converted to float before calling `divide_1000` thus precision gets lost before the calculation is done. It would be interesting to see what happens here when a flag is passed to the compiler to use strict floating point semantics. I would expect the same results in both cases.

Comment: @Axel After thinking a little I agree with you. Worst case it's a bug in the compiler. I suggest for the OP to check the generated assembly code, and to try with different optimization levels (including none).

Comment: @Axel I tryed to use "Strict (/fp:strict)" in comiple, but the result doesn't change.

Comment: @hdbean yes I saw it, I meant that for example gcc (4.7.2) gives you the "expected" result, treating both cases the same. Axel pointed to something that could be relevant about what could be the difference.

Comment: Why float, rather than double? One of the merits of double is that every 32-bit integer is exactly representable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few code generation settings involved here that affect the outcome. The difference that you report is observable in non-optimized code under default floating point model (i.e. "precise" model) when using the "classic" FPU instructions for floating-point computations.

The compiler translates the first call literally: the original integer value is first converted to `float` - 4-byte floating-point value - stored in memory (as function argument). This conversion rounds the value to `+6.7975504e+7`, which is already not precise. Later that  `float` value is read form memory inside the first function and used for further computations.

The second call passes an `int` value to the function, which is directly loaded into high-precision FPU register and used for further computations. Even though you specified an explicit conversion from `int` to `float` inside the second function, the compiler decided to ignore your request. This value is never literally converted to `float`, meaning that the aforementioned loss of precision never occurs.

That is what is causing the difference you observed.

If you rewrite your second function as

```
float divide_1000(int y)
{
    float fy = y;
    float v = fy / 1000.0f;
    return v;
}
```

i.e. add an additional step that saves the `float` value to a named location in memory, the compiler will perform that step in non-optimized code. This will cause the results to become identical.

Again, the above applies to the code compiled without optimizations, when the compiler normally attempts to translate all statements very closely (but not always exactly). In optimized code the compiler eliminates the "unnecessary" intermediate conversions to `float` and all "unnecessary" intermediate memory stores in both cases, producing identical results.

You might also want to experiment with other floating-point models (i.e. "strict" and "fast") to see how it affects the results. These floating-point models exist specifically to deal with issues like the one you observed.

If you change code generation settings of the compiler and make it use SSE instructions for floating-point arithmetic, the results might also change (in my experiment the difference disappears when SSE2 instruction set is used instead of FPU instructions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have use `unsigned int mode_87 = 0; 
    int ret = __control87_2(0, 0, &mode_87, 0);
    ret = __control87_2(_RC_NEAR, _MCW_RC, &mode_87, 0);
    ret = __control87_2(_PC_24, _MCW_PC, &mode_87, 0);
` to control the precision. Will the MSVC still use FPU registers?

Comment: @hdbean: By default MSVC will use FPU instructions and FPU registers to perform floating-point computations. But if you go to project settings -> C/C++ -> Code Generation and set "Enable Enhanced Instruction Set" to "SSE2", the compiler will switch to SSE instructions for handling floating-point computations. The results might change in that case.

Comment: In SSE2 code generation mode I get identical results even under default settings in non-optimized code.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my project, I can't use SSE2, so I have to use math87 mode. By the way, have you try which is more efficient SSE2 or math87?